# Angular: Как работает событие toggle?

Tags: angular

Заметил благодаря IDE, что существует событие (toggle).

Например здесь:

```
<button (toggle)="test($event)">Click me</button>
```

Нигде не нашел что это за событие такое и как с ним работать. Может быть вы знаете?

Comment: @entithat Молчит как рыба!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Событие `toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDetailsElement/toggle_event) используют на тэге `details`[<sup>[1]</sup>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-toggle).

```
<details (toggle)="test($event)">Click</details>
```

P.S. Кликая на кнопку вы ничего не увидите, потому что срабатывает событие клика.

Comment: Ого, первый раз о таком теге слышу, спасибо!))

Comment: @Митяй, это что-то вроде спойлера. Пожалуйста